# Redux-form: Prevent Input automatically fill prop.input.value with selected files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I have a component which I use in Field component={{}}

And inside it I have input type="file"
So when I'm selecting files it automatically fills prop.input.value with selected files.

But I want to manualy fill prop.input.value onChange with modified files object.

How can I prevent it automatically fills props.input.value when I select files?

Answer (score 0):

You can not call onChange so youll have

```
<Field component={({input:{onChange}})=> {<input type="file" >} name={name} />
```

The value will be peristed on the store when you call that `onChange` function
meaning you can do whatever you want in the middle

```
 <Field component={({input:{onChange}})=> {<input type="file" onChange={(theValueOrValueContainerEvent)=>
 {....whateveryouwant; onChange(theValueOrValueContainerEvent) }}>} name={name} />
```

so after you do your whatever you want and you are ready you can call onChange from redux-form to perist the change.

Hope it helps